# Terminal Server 2008: Remote App Issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, terminal-server, remoteapp, remote-desktop-services

I have a FoxPro 2.6 (16-bit) application that I've installed on a Win2008 (32-bit) Terminal Server. I then created a Remote App from it. It works fine. The problem is that within this FoxPro application it calls out to a .Net application. I have the proper .Net Framework installed on the server (2.0) and I have run the code access security policy tool (caspol.exe). However, when I launch the .Net app from within the FoxPro application I get the following error:

Description:
  Stopped working

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: vector.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.3
  Problem Signature 03: 48b579f2
  Problem Signature 04: vector
  Problem Signature 05: 1.0.0.3
  Problem Signature 06: 48b579f2
  Problem Signature 07: f
  Problem Signature 08: 57
  Problem Signature 09: System.Security.Security
  OS Version:   6.0.6001.2.1.0.18.10
  Locale ID:    1033

Vector.exe is our .Net application. In fact, it's an in-between application that checks to ensure you have the latest version. When it's done it calls out to another .Net executable. Does anyone believe this should be a problem?

Thanks in advance.

### Update #1:

I just figured out that the version of the framework I needed to have installed was 3.5. After installing this everything seems to work fine. However, there are now two applications running in the same remote app. The .Net app is sitting behind the FoxPro app but there is no way to get to it. If you minimize FoxPro you minimize the entire window. Any suggestions on how to move between multiple applications in the same Remote App?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure RemoteApp isn't designed to work with multiple discrete applications launching. You publish A remote app-not 'A remote app and any apps that it calls'. I believe in your scenario you'd probably want to go with a full TS session-it would allow you to alt-tab between windows.